# How to check if a timespan in negative. C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

The title says it all. I'm subtracting two DateTimes and I want to see if the returned Timespan is negative. How do I do this?

```
// dt1 and dt2 are DateTimes.
TimeSpan ts = dt1.Subtract(dt2);
ts.isNegative() // or something like that
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: TimeSpan has a compare method on it, or you can do `< TimeSpan.Zero` or you could have just compared the two DateTimes in the first place.

Comment: `myTimeSpan < TimeSpan.Zero`?

Comment: I tried the < TimeSpan.Zero and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TimeSpan` has a `Compare` method on it, or you can do `< TimeSpan.Zero` or you could have just compared the two DateTimes in the first place and skipped creating the `TimeSpan` entirely.